# Reading in textfile into Stack and print out elements in reverse order

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to read in a text file (lines of text), putting all elements into a stack using the push method. Once I do that I plan on printing all elements - line by line using the pop method.

- Read input one line at a time and then write the lines out in
- reverse order, so that the last input line is printed first, then
- the second last input line, and so on.

```
class part1{

    //pushing element on the top of the stack 
    static void stack_push(Stack<String> stack){
        for(int i = 0; i< stack.length(); i++){
            stack.push(i);
        }
    }

    static void stack_pop(Stack<String> stack){
        System.out.println("Pop :");

        for(int i = 0; i < stack.length(); i++){
            String y = (String) stack.pop();
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("randomFile.txt"));
        stack_push(br);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. You are passing an object of `BufferedReader` to `stack_push` but this method does not have any matching parameter.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm confused as to how I am supposed to push each line from the textfile to the stack

Comment: @bobbyverm - Go through some basic tutorial like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html to understand how to read lines from a file. Add a line to the stack as you read it.

Comment: Why are you passing buffered reader as Stack<String> and why are you pushing into this very stack integers?

Answer (score 0):

Iterative ("classical") approach of reading a file and pushing the contents of it into a stack:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fileName = "randomFile.txt";

   // create a bufferedReader 
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {

        // create a stack (Note: do not use the Stack class here, it is inherited from Vector which is deprecated.)
        Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // read the file line by line and push the lines into the stack
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stack.push(line);
        }

        // pop the values from the stack and print them
        while (stack.peek() != null) {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Declarative ("modern") approach:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fileName = "randomFile.txt";
    // create stream from the input file
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        // create a stack (Note: do not use the Stack class here, it is inherited from Vector which is deprecated.)
        Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // push the lines from the stream into the stack
        stream.forEach(stack::push);

        // print the lines from the stack (Note: the stack is not modified here!)
        stack.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```